# Editing the normal direction to be parallel with the face.

Tags: normals

So I am looking to change the normal direction from being 90° on the face to just kind of lay flat on the face. Is that possible to achieve in Blender? Or are there any addons that will help with this?

Comment: May I ask why you want to do that? It is just that blender calculates its normals. They are not something that can easily be modified.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify specific normals of specific faces of a mesh, the only way I know of is the "Normal Edit" modifier.

Basically you create a vertex group, containing all the faces you want the normals changed of. Then add the Normal Edit modifier, choose Directional, select the vertex group and pick a target object. After that all normals of all faces of the selected vertex group will point in the direction of the center of the target object. If you want the normals be parallel, select Parallel Normals in the modifier.

Comment: Hmmm, when I enter edit mode to see the normal as shown by a line coming out of the face it just stays at a 90° angle from the face regardless of what I do.